# Python reading from file encoding problem

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, cp1252

when I read like this, some files

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt') # create the list of files
for file_name in list_of_files:
    FI = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='cp1252')
```

Error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1260: character maps to

When I switch to this

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt') # create the list of files
for file_name in list_of_files:
    FI = open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
```

Error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1459: invalid start byte

And I have read that I should open this as a binary file. But I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my function:

```
def readingAndAddToList():
    list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt') # create the list of files
    for file_name in list_of_files:
        FI = open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
        stext = textProcessing(FI.read())# split returns a list of words delimited by sequences of whitespace (including tabs, newlines, etc, like re's \s)
        secondaryWord_list = stext.split()
        word_list.extend(secondaryWord_list) # Add words to main list
        print("Lungimea fisierului ",FI.name," este de", len(secondaryWord_list), "caractere")
        sortingAndNumberOfApparitions(secondaryWord_list)
        FI.close()
```

Just the beggining of my functions matter because I get the error at the reading part

Comment: Can you try with ```open(file_name, 'r', errors = 'ignore')```? Does it give you required output?

Comment: Can you share problematic file? Or identify yourself problematic symbol(s) that causes exception?

Comment: @Hello.World it worked in this way. Because those characters where something like " ' " which I don't need at all

Comment: @Adrian Yes I did think that was the issue. I didn't have sample for your file so told you to try! Anyways happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows,open the file in NotePad and save as desired encoding .
In Linux , DO the same in text editor. 
hope your program runs.